# How do I get WTP added into FlexBuilder 3

Tags: eclipse, flexbuilder, eclipse-wtp

Has anyone managed to get Eclipse WTP working underneath FlexBuilder 3, or get FlexBuilder 3 and WTP working in a vanilla Eclipse install?

I had this all working fine with FlexBuidler 2 and Eclipse 3.2, but the FlexBuilder 3 I have is a standalone app and I'm struggling to get any other Eclipse plug-ins to work with it.